# How to debug Visual Studio environment variable usage?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am unable to change my PATH environment variable from Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express using a project relative path.

Relevant paths:

- **Solution path:** `D:\School\dva303\project\Woods\`
- **Project path:** `D:\School\dva303\project\Woods\Woods\`
- **Absolute path to needed DLL directory:** `D:\School\dva303\project\Woods\Woods\allegro-5.0.10-msvc-11.0\bin`

When I use the absolute path:

- Project Properties / Debugging / Environment: `PATH=D:\School\dva303\project\Woods\Woods\allegro-5.0.10-msvc-11.0\bin`

It works! But if I change it to a project relative one using `$(ProjectDir)`:

- Project Properties / Debugging / Environment: `PATH=$(ProjectDir)\allegro-5.0.10-msvc-11.0\bin`

It fails and I get a message that the DLL can not be found on my computer. It does not matter if I use a `\` after `$(ProjectDir)` or not.

Questions:

1. How do I get it to work?
2. How do you debug situations like this one when a Visual Studio environment variable is not behaving as you expect it to? Is there a way to print it out or by some other method see what it will be evaluated to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a post build task to echo out `$(var)`, and you'll see it in the output window.

I think your actual problem is that your environment variables don't propagate to the application you run/debug. You can use SysInternals' [Process Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Explorer) to check this. If so, just add another post build task to copy the required DLL files to the same directory as your output.

If you just want to see the values of `$(ProjectDir)` then if you go in to your vcxproj properties, then anything then lets you get to the "macros" view. Such as adding a new include path will list these out and their values. But you'll still need the echo trick for anything "dynamic" or to check nothing is overriding it.

Comment: Well it does work when I use an absolute path. It does not work when I do not merge PATH information at all. So it seem to me that it propagates. I will try the debugging suggestion now!

Comment: Probably $(ProjectDir) is not what you expect

Comment: This way of debugging worked! I had an accidental space immediately after `PATH=` which messed my PATH up. It works now!